# Reading bucket from another project in cloudshell

Tags: import, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, acl

Because Firestore does not have a way to clone projects, I am attempting to achieve the equivalent by copying data from one project into a GCS bucket and read it into another project.

Specifically, using cloudshell I populate the bucket with data exported from Firestore project A and am attempting to import it into Firestore project B. The bucket belongs to Firestore project A.

I am able to export the data from Firestore project A without any issue.  When I attempt to import into Firestore project B with the cloudshell command

```
gcloud beta firestore import gs://bucketname
```

I get the error message

```
project-b@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.
buckets.get access to bucketname
```

I have searched high and low for a way to provide the access rights storage.bucket.get to project B, but am not finding anything that works.

Can anyone point me to how this is done?  I have been through the Google docs half a dozen times and am either not finding the right information or not understanding the information that I find.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get the commands provided by "sotis" to work, however his answer certainly got me heading down the right path.  The commands that eventually worked for me were:

```
    gcloud config set project [SOURCE_PROJECT_ID]
    gcloud beta firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME]

    gcloud config set project [TARGET_PROJECT_ID]    
    gsutil acl ch -u [RIGHTS_RECIPIENT]:R gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
    gcloud beta firestore import gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[TIMESTAMPED_DIRECTORY]
```

Where:

```
* SOURCE_PROJECT_ID = the name of the project you are cloning
* TARGET_PROJECT_ID = the destination project for the cloning
* RIGHTS_RECIPIENT = the email address of the account to receive read rights
* BUCKET_NAME = the name of the bucket that stores the data.  
      Please note, you have to manually create this bucket before you export to it.  
      Also, make sure the bucket is in the same geographic region as the projects you are working with.
* TIMESTAMPED_DIRECTORY = the name of the data directory automatically created by the "export" command
```

I am sure that this is not the only way to solve the problem, however it worked for me and appears to be the "shortest path" solution I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

For import from a project A in a project B, the service account in project B must have the right permissions for the Cloud Storage bucket in project A.

In your case, the service account is:

- `project-ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`

To grant the right permissions you can use [this command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl) on the Cloud Shell of project B:

```
gsutil acl ch -u project-ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:OWNER gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
gsutil -m acl ch -r -u project-ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:OWNER gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

Then, you can import using the [firestore import](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import#import_data):

```
gcloud beta firestore import gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[EXPORT_PREFIX]
```